# Testing Truthy or Falsy arguments passed through a function into an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, truthiness

I am drawing a blank on this one too. Rather than provide an answer, I would appreciate if someone could help me understand why my code is not printing the expected output:

```
def bool_to_str(bval):
    if bval is True:
        mytest = 'Yes'
    else:
        mytest = 'No'
    return mytest
```

Expected output:

```
>>>bool_to_str([1, 2, 3])
'Yes'
>>>bool_to_str(abcdef)
'Yes'
```

What's actually output:

```
>>>bool_to_str([1, 2, 3])
'No'
>>>bool_to_str(abcdef)
'No'
```

Please help me to understand what I did wrong. I think that the function needs to test the actual truth value of the argument, but I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Given your function names I guess you actually want to test if the input is actually a bool and then convert it to string, you could use `isinstance(bval,bool)` to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`is` checks reference equality**, not *truthiness*. Now clearly `[1,2,3]` (which is a `list` object) does **not point to the `True` object** (which is `bool` object). It is hard to say if `abcdef` which is not defined here points to `True`. But since you do not provide it, I gonna assume it points to something different.

Only `bool_to_str(True)` or `bool_to_str(<expr>)` where `<expr>` **evaluates to a `bool`** that is `True` will result in `'Yes'` (the `bool`s are singletons, so all `True`s are the same object).

The point is that in order to **check the truthness of `<expr>`, simply write `if <expr>:`**. So in your case it should be:

```
if bval:
```

You can also - although I advise *against* it, check the truthness explicitly with `bool(..)` and check reference equality like:

```
if bool(bval) is True:
```

Usually it is not a good idea to write `is`. Only if you want to check if two variables point to the *same* (i.e. **not** *equivalent*) object, or for some singleton objects like `True`, `None`, `()`, etc. it makes really sense.

Comment: This triggered a memory of one of the topics on truthiness. if bval: is correct. It makes sense that I should be checking the argument alone without specifying if it is true. Thanks for the informative answer. It helped me understand.

Answer (score 8):

`bval is True` checks to see whether `[1, 2, 3]` actually is the *True* object.   You need something like `bool()` to evaluate whether an object is a true value but not identical to the *True* object.

Comment: I tried this as well and it works too. Willem's answer below is more in line with what I was taught (so far as the course is only 7 weeks in).

Answer (score 0):

`[1,2,3]` does not equal `True`, however, if you put in something like `1`, then `1 == True` would pass but when you use `is` it will always be False unless it is `True`